# AndroidStudio not recognizing RelativeLayout subclass as a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Hopefully this question will resolve to me having incorrect expectations, but I'm using Android Studio 0.2.10 and am having problems with the rendering system recognizing the XML for a custom view group extending RelativeLayout as an actual RelativeLayout. The effects of this are that children in the custom view aren't getting options that should be available to them... layout_width, layout_height or alignComponent for instance (which seems to indicate that it's not even recognizing the custom layout as a layout at all).

I can of course just add these attributes to the XML manually or just set the root tag to RelativeLayout temporarily and the design tool seems to work fine, but I'm curious if, because AndroidStudio is failing to resolve the custom extension properly, I'm doing something wrong by design. I'm new to Android development, so I didn't want to lob this away as an IDE bug prematurely.

```
public class CommentCellView extends RelativeLayout {
    private static String TAG = "CommentCellView";

    final private CommentCellView _cellView;
    private Comment _comment;

    public CommentCellView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _cellView = this;
    }

    public CommentCellView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _cellView = this;
    }

    public CommentCellView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        _cellView = this;
    }

    public void setComment(Comment comment) {
        _comment = comment;

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.commentcell_nameTextView);
        TextView commentTextView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.commentcell_commentTextView);
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.commentcell_dateTextView);

        nameTextView.setText(comment.name);
        commentTextView.setText(comment.comment);
        dateTextView.setText(comment.date);
    }
}

<com.testapp.CommentCellView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/commentcell_backgroundImageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/comment_bg"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/commentcell_avatarImageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/commentcell_nameTextView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/commentcell_avatarImageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commentcell_avatarImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/commentcell_commentTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/commentcell_nameTextView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/commentcell_nameTextView"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/commentcell_dateTextView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/commentcell_avatarImageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commentcell_avatarImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</com.testapp.CommentCellView>
```

Comment: Please post your layout, so we can give you a better answer. Thanks.

Comment: Studio works just fine with custom views.  Please post your code (only the custom view) and layout.  However, your view constructors must work with no dependencies on external classes which will only be instantiated at runtime.  You should use `isEditMode` if you need conditional code at design time. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Comment: I can't see any problem with this, but you do  not need (and should not use) `_cellView`.  Just use `this` to refer to the current instance.  Check the Studio error log to see why the view is not being rendered.  BTW, if all you want to do is add a comment to a `RelativeKLayout`, just use `setTag()`

Comment: Thanks for looking over my code. The view renders fine, the problem is that the design tool isn't treating it like a layout so in the properties panel on the left attributes are missing that would be there if I was editing a RelativeLayout directly. As such, there aren't any actual errors thrown that I can find. And you're right for the _cellView method variable, I put that in there as a means of referring to this particular view in runnables and click listeners without having to map "this" to a final variable in every place I will end up needing it... this is just a skeleton class so far.